# is it possible load a file.js.erb in <head></head>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, coffeescript

I have a `file.js.erb` file in my views, but I need load this file in `<head></head>` layout.

Is it possible load these files in `<head></head>` section?

and if it's possible, How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use `content_for` and a `yield` in your layout if you need to include javascripts on several pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your layout:

```html
<head>
  <script><%=render :file => "layouts/file.js"%></script>
</head>
```

If the file contains script tags then you wouldn't need them in the layout,  and change the layouts in the path to wherever the file actually is.

---

If you don't want it on every page then you can use content_for and yield  (as MyYorshiji suggests in the comments)

```html
<head>
  <script><%= yield :extra_js %> </script>
</head>
```

In the view html.erb where you want this js to load

```
<%content_for :extra_js do %> 
  <%=render :file => "layouts/file.js"%>
<% end %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for

Comment: Thank you is working fine in development. However I don't know if this tag `<script><%= yield :extra_js %> </script>`  will throw errors when it will make precompile assets with deployment in production. Is it possible add `<script>` tag to `application.js` file with something like, `//= require extra_js` Thank you

Comment: extra_js is just the symbol I used for the content_for/yield.  I'm assuming the file.js.erb is in app/views/something.   It is treated like any other partial in app/views and wouldn't be precompiled.

Comment: I'm getting this message with my specs: `......DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a template handler in the template name is deprecated. You can simply remove the handler name or pass render :handlers => [:erb] instead. (called from block (2 levels) in...` thank you!

Comment: @hyperrjas Yes, just leave off the .erb in the render line , I've edited to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you, I have removed the message with `<%= render :file => "layouts/file" :formats => [:js] %>` Thank you again!